# Caffe throws mkl error while importing using mod_wsgi and httpd

Tags: apache, anaconda, mod-wsgi, caffe, intel-mkl

I have a flask app which uses caffe compiled with mkl. The app is working fine when running using flask internal server or gunicorn. But when i try to run it using mod_wsgi and httpd, it throws the following error:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load <mkl-loader>.
```

I am using Anaconda 4.1.1 which comes with mkl. For httpd, i am using mpm prefork and mod_wsgi 4.5.3 (i tried older and newer versions as well).

Note: caffe imports fine when done outside httpd/mod_wsgi.